# How has someone I don't know competed in my alphabear verses match?

Tags: alphabear

I challenged a friend with a verses match in alphabear,  but someone else competed as well. How did they do that when I didn't share the link with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone can play in any verses match.  This is possible due  to the "Random Challenge" option. I have confirmed this with Spryfox via  email.

> Spry Fox Support (Ray), Mar 14, 1:03 PM:
>   Yes, any challenge can be selected at random by the random match option by default.
>
> -Ray (Spry Fox Support)

When asked about switching it off:

> Spry Fox Support (Ray), Mar 14, 10:11 PM:
>   Sorry, we don't have that option at this time. However, I can relay it to the dev team as a suggestion!
>
> -Ray (Spry Fox Support)

[Ticket](https://spryfox.zendesk.com/requests/14782#)